# Piano score in Musixtex with Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-arrows, musixtex

It is needed to implement a Piano score in Musixtex with Beamer, When use the colorbox command it seems Musixtex not working on Beamer, but it is needed as I use a background color from Beamer template; the basic code is as follow:

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: xelatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{gray-undar}{RGB}{52,52,52}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{\LARGE Partes de una Partitura}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0,rotate=0,transform shape,scale=1] (partitura) at (0,0) {
        \colorbox{white}{\hspace*{-0.4cm}\begin{music}
        \setstaffs{1}{2}
        \setclef1\bass
        \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
        \generalsignature{2} % Una armadura en Fa y Do Sostenido
        \generalmeter{\meterfrac{4}{4}} %Compás en 4/4
        \startextract % Se inicia el fragmento musical
        %\scale{1.7}
        \Notes\hp\qu{C}|\ca e\en
        \Notes\qsk|\ca l\en
        \Notes\qp|\ibu0f2\qb0f\en
        \Notes\qsk|\tbu0\qb0g\en
        \NOTes\qp|\hp\en\bar
        \NOtes\pause|\pause\en
        \endextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
        \end{music}}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(partitura.south east)},y={(partitura.north west)}]
        % \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
        %     \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
        %     \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
        \draw[red-undar,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.77,0.57) rectangle (0.85,0.86);%Figuras Musicales
        %\node[circle,draw=red-undar,ultra thick,minimum size=14] (c) at (0.545,0.4){};%Alteraciones        
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
        
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow (note that the notes of the C clef are not aligned according that clef):
[image: current]

The desired output is as follow:
[image: desired]

Comment: Can you try without the `\colorbox`?

Comment: The result seems to be the same with article class https://pastebin.com/Nm5k1uty , so it seems to not be a beamer problem

Comment: That´s right when not using the colorbox it works fine!!! But unfortunately it is needed as I use a template background color in beamer. Is it another way to solve this?

Comment: You can us `filll=white` in the tikz node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to come from the `\colorbox`. You can avoid it by setting a fill colour for the TikZ node instead of using a `\colorbox`:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{gray-undar}{RGB}{52,52,52}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{\LARGE Partes de una Partitura}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0,rotate=0,transform shape,scale=1,fill=green] (partitura) at (0,0) {
%        \colorbox{white}{
        \hspace*{-0.4cm}\begin{music}
        \setstaffs{1}{2}
        \setclef1\bass
        \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
        \generalsignature{2} % Una armadura en Fa y Do Sostenido
        \generalmeter{\meterfrac{4}{4}} %Compás en 4/4
        \startextract % Se inicia el fragmento musical
        %\scale{1.7}
        \Notes\hp\qu{C}|\ca e\en
        \Notes\qsk|\ca l\en
        \Notes\qp|\ibu0f2\qb0f\en
        \Notes\qsk|\tbu0\qb0g\en
        \NOTes\qp|\hp\en\bar
        \NOtes\pause|\pause\en
        \endextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
        \end{music}
%        }
        };
    \begin{scope}[x={(partitura.south east)},y={(partitura.north west)}]
        % \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
        %     \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
        %     \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
        \draw[red-undar,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.67,0.57) rectangle (0.75,0.86);%Figuras Musicales
        %\node[circle,draw=red-undar,ultra thick,minimum size=14] (c) at (0.545,0.4){};%Alteraciones        
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
        
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]